# How do I achieve the task of distributing my index table over 3 systems?

Tags: java, indexing, distributed-computing

I want to achieve something like this

Given a document say a txt file with an id, I need to process it, do stemming on the words, and generate a index table out of it. But this index table is distributed over 3 systems probably on the basis of the criteria that words beginning with letters from [a-h] are indexed on 1st system, next one third on second and last one third on 3rd system. But i have no idea what technology should i use to achieve this? The index table data structure in ought to be in the RAM so that the search queries can be answered quickly(supposing we are able to index it in this way and have a user searching for a word or sentence from different system). Can this purpose be fulfilled by use of JAVA Sockets?

Actually we(group of 5) are trying to make a small but distributed search engine. Supposing the crawling has been done and the page(the document i was talking about) is saved somewhere and i extract it, do the processing , stemming etc, I would like to finally make a distributed Index data structure based on scheme mentioned above. Would it be possible? I just want to know what technology to use to achieve something like this. Like modifying a data structure inside some program running on some other machine(but in the same network).

Secondly, since we actually don't know if this approach is feasible, if thats the case I would be keen to know the correct way I should look at a distributed index table.

Answer (score 0):

Have the index information saved as you crawl the documents.  Have a head node which presents the search user interface.  The head node then distributes the search to the index nodes, and collects the results to present to the user.

There are a number of available frameworks, such as Mapreduce, which will help you solve this problem.